# How to convert a 2d array to a sudoku image in svg or png format?

Tags: c++, image, svg, sudoku

I am trying to make a sudoku generator in C++, for which I have the resulting puzzle stored as a 2D matrix. How can I generate an svg image or png image of that array like a sudoku?

Like I know I can use many tools like svg++, Qt, simple-svg, and from the answer of @Marek R, I think Qt's QImage will be good to go, but I wanted to know is there a way I can load an existing sudoku, and just change the values in it's cell rather than drawing it myself ? Is it possible in Qt, if not is there any other way for it ?

Comment: You draw it using a library that provides such functionality. [Qt has QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html), for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll use Qt than it is quite simple:

```
void SomeClass::paintSvg(const QString &path)
{
    QSvgGenerator generator;
    generator.setFileName(path);
    generator.setSize(QSize(200, 200));
    generator.setViewBox(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200));
    generator.setTitle(tr("Sudoku problem"));
    generator.setDescription(tr("An SVG drawing created by the SVG Generator "
                                "Example provided with Qt."));

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&generator);
    paintSudokuOn(painter);
    painter.end();
}

void SomeClass::paintPng(const QString &path) {
    QImage image { {200, 200}, QImage::Format_RGB32 };

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&image);
    paintSudokuOn(painter);
    painter.end();

    image.save(path);
}

void SomeClass::paintSudokuOn(QPainter &painter) {
     // your code to do drawing
}
```

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-svggenerator-example.html

Comment: Is it possible that rather than drawing the full puzzle myself, can I just load an existing sudoku and just change the entries in cells?

Comment: If you have ready widget than you can use [QWidget::render](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render) to perform this rendering.